# What is the activator command to generate application secret?

Tags: playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I'm using [Play Framework 2.3.6](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.6/Home). Since Play 2.3.x `play` commands are replaced with `activator` commands. [Play's documentation for 2.3.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ApplicationSecret) as well as latest 2.4.x mentions commands `play-generate-secret` and `play-update-secret` but I am not able to find corresponding `activator` commands.

We may not choose to use these secrets for production environment but would like play to generate secrets for integration and pre-prod environments - which we can change frequently.

Has anyone done this before? What are the proper activator commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both

```
activator play-generate-secret
```

and

```
activator play-update-secret
```

work well for the Activator.

You can find their definition [here in the sources](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayImport.scala#L159). And as you can see they are part of Play and not the Activator.

```
val generateSecret = TaskKey[String]("play-generate-secret", "Generate a new application secret", KeyRanks.BTask)
val updateSecret = TaskKey[File]("play-update-secret", "Update the application conf to generate an application secret", KeyRanks.BTask)
```

Comment: Brilliant! That works perfect. I tried 'activator help' but couldn't find it in the listing. Also tried executing 'play-generate-secret' directly(without activator) but didn't think of 'activator play-generate-secret'(bit of a shame!)  Thanks

Comment: in 2.4.x it seems it is `playGenerateSecret`

Answer (score 3):

As the comment from @john mentions, this is

```
activator playGenerateSecret
```

from Play 2.4 onwards.